# Sort on two variables

Tags: php, theme-customizer

I am trying to get my listings (Elegant Themes - eList) to sort by a custom field and then the name.

I have tried to include two order by statements, but I cannot get the listings to sort.

in the for each statement I am returning the posi

```
    $posi = get_post_meta($post->ID,'feature_posi',true);
```

I have a custom field that is filled with 1, 2 , 3.

I am trying to get the listings to show 1, 2, 3, and then sort the remaining listing by the title.

I have included all my code below.

I am a n00b and trying to get my head around PHP sorts.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
    <section id="recent-listings">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <?php $et_queried_object = get_queried_object();
?>
      <?php if ( ( isset( $et_queried_object ) && 'listing_tag' != $et_queried_object->taxonomy ) || is_home() ) {
    ?>
        <?php
}
?>
          <?php
$et_term = get_queried_object();

$et_count = 0;

$et_divider = 1;


if ( is_home() ){

    $et_divider = 1;

}
else {

    echo '<div id="main_content">';

    $term_t = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

    echo '<h2 class="listing-category-title">' . $term_t->name . '</h2>';


}


$et_divider = apply_filters( 'et_divider', $et_divider );

$et_open = false;

$term = $wp_query->queried_object;

$zdfs= $term->name;


$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );

$taxonomyName = 'listing_category';

$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );



$args = array(
'post_type' => 'listing',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tax_query'=>array(
array(
'taxonomy'=>$taxonomyName,
'field'=>$term_slug,
'terms'=> get_queried_object()->term_id,
)
)
);


$query = new WP_Query($args);



$posi = get_post_meta($post->ID,'feature_posi',true)  ;

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

$et_count++;

$et_open = true;

$et_is_last = $et_count % $et_divider == 0;



$z = strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'listing_category', '', ', ' ));

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'listing_category', '' );

$post_terms = array();

foreach ($terms as $post_term) {

    $post_terms[] = $post_term->term_id;
    $posi = get_post_meta($post->ID,'feature_posi',true);
    $xlink = get_post_meta($post->ID,'ExternalLink',true);
    $thumb = '';
                        $width = 230;
                        $height = 100;
                        $classtext = 'post-thumb';
                        $titletext = get_the_title();
                        $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Entry' );
                        $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];


}

$pos = strpos($z, $zdfs);

if ($pos === false) {
}

else {
    ?>

<li>
<img src="<?php echo $thumb ; ?>">
<?php echo $posi ; ?>

<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $xlink ; ?>" class="link_list<?php echo $posi ; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>



</li>
            <?php
}

if ( ! is_home() && $et_is_last ) {

    if ( is_tax() && ( $term->term_id == $post_terms[0]) ) echo '<div class="hr"></div>';

    $et_open = false;

}

?>

              <?php
endwhile;

ob_start();

echo '<div id="taxonomy_pagination">';

if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {
    wp_pagenavi();
}

else {
    get_template_part('includes/navigation','entry');
}

echo '</div> <!-- end #taxonomy_pagination -->';

$et_navigation = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

endif;

if ( ! is_home() ) {

    if ( $et_open ) echo '<div class="hr"></div>';

    if ( isset( $et_navigation ) && ! is_tax() ) echo $et_navigation;

    echo '</div> <!-- end #main_content -->';

    get_sidebar();

}

?></div>
  <!-- end .container -->
</section>
<!-- end #recent-listings -->
<?php if ( is_home() && isset( $et_navigation ) ) echo $et_navigation;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as every listing has a `feature_posi` field (even if it's empty), you can let WordPress/MySQL handle the ordering for you:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'listing',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'       => 'feature_posi',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomyName,
            'field'    => $term_slug,
            'terms'    => get_queried_object()->term_id,
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but they don't all have the feature_posi.  Could I prefix the $posi with the Title and sort on that?

Comment: Yes absolutely, but then you'll have the sorting number in the title, which you'll need to remove on the frontend if you don't want it to show.